# Why do my nib sizes keep changing without my permission?

Tags: autolayout, interface-builder, xcode7, ios-autolayout

Every time I run the app my nib files seem to update themselves.

Usually the differences are 1px or 0.5px changes in sizes.

e.g.

```
<color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
<nil key="highlightedColor"/>
<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
-                                                <rect key="frame" x="18" y="49" width="89" height="12.5"/>
+                                                <rect key="frame" x="18" y="49" width="89" height="12"/>
</variation>
</label>
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="ABCD1234" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="eb0-K9-hzy">
@@ -4813,7 +4813,7 @@ Share with friends</string>
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="240" height="128"/>
<color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
-                                            <rect key="frame" x="50" y="34" width="300" height="50.5"/>
+                                            <rect key="frame" x="50" y="34" width="300" height="51"/>
</variation>
</view>
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="TWEET" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VdA-A5-lp1">
@@ -6283,7 +6283,7 @@ Share with friends</string>
</mask>
</variation>
<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
-                                    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="159" width="139" height="1"/>
+                                    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="159" width="138.5" height="1"/>
<mask key="constraints">
<include reference="RHR-oC-Ve5"/>
</mask>
@@ -6311,7 +6311,7 @@ Share with friends</string>
</mask>
</variation>
<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
-                                    <rect key="frame" x="242" y="159" width="138" height="1"/>
+                                    <rect key="frame" x="241" y="159" width="138.5" height="1"/>
<mask key="constraints">
<include reference="HZ8-ae-IUF"/>
</mask>
@@ -6354,7 +6354,7 @@ Share with friends</string>
</mask>
</variation>
<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
-                                    <rect key="frame" x="164" y="150" width="73" height="19"/>
+                                    <rect key="frame" x="163" y="150" width="73" height="19"/>
```

(see the height difference on lines 3 and 4)

I'm using auto-layout. Is this common for AutoLayout? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this happens often when you use source control. Are you using source control ?

Comment: Yes. Isn't everyone?